# Choosing $10$ balls from $4$ boxes each having $3$ distinct red balls and $2$ distinct blue balls when at least $1$ of each colour is chosen in a box

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Consider $4$ boxes, where each box contains $3$ red balls and $2$ blue balls. Assume that all $20$ balls are distinct.  In how many different ways can $10$ balls be chosen from these $4$ boxes such that from each box at least $1$ red ball and $1$ blue ball is chosen?

I proceeded by first selecting a red ball and a blue ball from each box, which I think can be done by $$\left(\binom{3}1 \binom{2}1 2!\right)^4=20376$$

Now I have chosen $8$ balls, so I have $2$ more left to choose. Since I've chosen $4$ red balls and $4$ blue balls in total, I've $8$ red and $4$ blue left.  So I can choose $2$ balls from them by either $2$ of one color and none from the other, or $1$ from each color. I can do that in

$$\binom{8}1 \binom{4}1 2! + \binom{8}2 2! + \binom {4}2 2!=132$$

So total number of required selections are $20376×132$.

However the correct answer is given as $21816$.

Where have I gone wrong and how do I get to the correct answer?

Comment: Are you considering choosing a Red ball from Box $1$ then Blue ball from box $2$ to be different from choosing a Blue ball from Box $2$ and then a red ball from box $1$? Or do you not care about the order of choice?

Comment: Few points: Your calculation in the first one is wrong. It should be 20736. But that doesn't fix the answer. See the answers below to see the proper solution. Also, $2!$ is useless as you don't need ordering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What did you do wrong?**

Note that designating particular balls to be the representative of that color in a particular box leads to overcounting whenever you have more than one ball of that color drawn from that box since such selections are counted once for each way you could have designated one of the balls of that color as the ball of that color.

To illustrate, suppose the red balls are numbered $r_{ij}$ and the blue balls are numbered $b_{ij}$, where $i$ denotes the box number and $j$ denotes the number in that box.  Then you count the selection $b_{11}, b_{12}, b_{21}, b_{31}, b_{41}, r_{11}, r_{12}, r_{21}, r_{31}, r_{41}$ four times.

\begin{array}{c c c c c}
\text{box 1} & \text{box 2} & \text{box 3} & \text{box 4} & \text{additional balls}\\ \hline
b_{11}, r_{11} & b_{21}, r_{21} & b_{31}, r_{31} & b_{41}, r_{41} & b_{12}, r_{12}\\
b_{11}, r_{12} & b_{21}, r_{21} & b_{31}, r_{31} & b_{41}, r_{41} & b_{12}, r_{11}\\
b_{12}, r_{11} & b_{21}, r_{21} & b_{31}, r_{31} & b_{41}, r_{41} & b_{11}, r_{12}\\
b_{12}, r_{12} & b_{21}, r_{21} & b_{31}, r_{31} & b_{41}, r_{41} & b_{11}, r_{11}
\end{array}

**Solution**

Let's consider cases, depending on how many balls of each color are chosen and how many balls are selected from each box.  Since at least one ball of each color must be selected from each box, there can be at most six balls of the same color.

*Six red and four blue balls are selected*

We must select a blue ball from each box, which can be done in $\binom{2}{1}^4$ ways.  For the red balls, there are two possibilities.  Either three red balls are selected from one box and one each is selected from the other three boxes, which can occur in $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{1}^3$ ways, or two red balls each are selected from two of the four boxes and one red ball each is selected from the other two boxes, which can occur in $\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2}^2\binom{3}{1}^2$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{2}{1}^4\left[\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{1}^3 + \binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2}^2\binom{3}{1}^2\right]$$
such selections.

*Five red and five blue balls are selected*

There are two possibilities.  We select two red balls and two blue balls from the same box and one ball of each color from each of the other boxes, which can occur in $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}^3\binom{2}{1}^3$ ways, or we can select two red balls from one box, one red ball each from the other three boxes, two blue balls from a box different than the box from which two red balls were selected, and one blue ball from each of the other three boxes, which can occur in $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}^3\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{1}^3$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}^3\binom{2}{1}^3 + \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}^3\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{1}^3$$
such selections.

*Four red and six blue balls are selected*

We must select one red ball from each box, which can occur in $\binom{3}{1}^4$ ways.  We must select two blue balls each from two of the four boxes and one blue ball from each of the other two boxes, which can occur in $\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}^2\binom{2}{1}^2$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{3}{1}^4\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}^2\binom{2}{1}^2$$
such selections.

*Total*:  Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of possible selections is
$$\binom{2}{1}^4\left[\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}\binom{3}{1}^3 + \binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2}^2\binom{3}{1}^2\right] + \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}^3\binom{2}{1}^3 + \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}^3\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{1}^3 + \binom{3}{1}^4\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}^2\binom{2}{1}^2$$

Comment: you have answered such as question before , it showed that where the overcounting occurs using a small case. I think if you give its link , then it can be much helpful for OP. I could not find the answer in your past answers

Comment: @SalmonFish  Rather than searching for such a problem, I added an example to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't fractionate selections from boxes, you have to select whatever you want from a box in one go.

There are only four distinct *patterns*

$\quad\;$ Pattern $1\quad\quad\quad$ Pattern $2\quad\quad\quad$ Pattern $3$

$R:3-1-1-1\; \;\; 2-1-1-1\;\;\;2-2-1-1$
$B:1-1-1-1\; \;\; 2-1-1-1\;\;\;1-1-1-1 $

Pattern $1: \binom33(\binom31)^3(\binom21)^4 *4 =1728$

Pattern $2: \binom32(\binom31)^3\binom22(\binom21)^3 *4^2 = 10368$

Pattern $3:(\binom32)^2(\binom31)^2*2^4 *\binom42 *1 = 7776$

Oh, there is a fourth pattern, $R=1-1-1-1, B = 2-2-1-1$

$(\binom31)^4 *(\binom22)^2(\binom21)^2*\binom42 = 1944$

Total: $21,816$

Basically, the steps for each pattern in sequence are:

- Choose numbers for red
- Choose numbers for blue
- Permute boxes

Answer (score 2):

Since we know we need at least two balls from each box, the only possible patterns are $4222$ and $3322$ in some order.  Let's treat each case separately.

In the $4222$ case, there are $4$ choices of the box that supplies $4$ balls.  We can choose any of the $5$ balls in that box to be the one left behind.  For the remaining $3$ boxes, we have $3$ choices of red ball to make and $2$ choices of blue ball, for a total of $6$ choices from each of those boxes.  Thus, the first case provides $4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6^3=4320$ combinations.

In the $3322$ case, there are $\binom 42=6$ choices of pairs of boxes to supply $3$ balls.  There are $\binom 53=10$ *unconstrained* choices of $3$ balls from each of those boxes.  However, one of those choices results in us selecting all three red balls, which is ruled out by the conditions of the problem.  Thus, we can choose $3$ balls from a box in $9$ permitted ways.  As before, we can choose $2$ balls from each of the other two boxes in $6$ permitted ways.  Therefore, the second case contributes $6 \cdot 9^2 \cdot 6^2=17496$ combinations.

Adding the two results, we get a total of $4320+17496=21816$ possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

$\underline{\text{Where you went wrong}}$ 
You over-counted.

For example, label each of the red balls as $R_{(x,y)}$, where $x \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, and $y\in \{1,2,3\}.$

So, $R_{(x,y)} =~$ the $y$-th ball from box $x$.

Consider the situation where (for example) the first red ball chosen from box-1 is $R_{(1,1)}$, and then a second ball, $R_{(1,2)}$ is also chosen from box-1.

The same distribution is over-counted by construing the first red ball chosen from box-1 to be $R_{(1,2)}$ and the second ball chosen to be $R_{(1,1,)}.$

So, although the red balls are distinguishable, the order that the red balls are chosen (or the order that any of the balls are chosen) is deemed to be irrelevant.

---

$\underline{\text{Attacking the Problem}}$

The number of red balls chosen from all of the boxes combined must be some element $~a \in \{4,5,6\}.$

Further, for each element $~a~$, you must then choose exactly $~(10-a)~$ blue balls.

Let $~f(a)~$ denote the number of ways of choosing $~a~$ red balls, and let $~g(a)~$ denote the number of ways of choosing $~(10-a)~$ blue balls.

Then, the desired computation will be

$$\sum_{a=4}^6 \left[f(a) \times g(a)\right]. \tag1 $$

Therefore, the problem has been reduced to computing the $~6~$ values $~f(a), g(a) ~: ~a \in \{4,5,6\},~$ and then applying the formula in (1) above.

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~f(a)}$

To select exactly $4$ red balls, you have to select $1$ from each box.  Therefore,

$$f(4) = 3^4 = 81.$$

To select exactly $5$ balls, you must select one of the $4$ boxes, and then choose exactly $2$ from the selected box.  Therefore,

$$f(5) = 4 \times \binom{3}{2} \times 3^3 = 324.$$

To select exactly $6$ balls, you must either select one of the boxes, and select all of its balls, or select two of the boxes, and select two each from the two selected boxes.  Therefore,

$$f(6) = \left[4 \times \binom{3}{3} \times 3^3\right]$$

$$+ \left[\binom{4}{2} \times \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{3}{2} \times 3^2\right]$$

$$= (108) + (6 \times 81) = 594.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Computation of} ~g(a)}$

When $a = 4,$ you are selecting $6$ blue balls.  To do this, you have to select two of the $4$ boxes, and then select both blue balls from the two selected boxes.  Then, you are selecting one of the two blue balls from each of the remaining two boxes.

So,

$$g(4) = \binom{4}{2} \times 2^2 = 24.$$

When $a = 5,$ you are selecting $5$ blue balls.  To do this, you have to select one of the $4$ boxes, and then select both blue balls from this box.  Then, you are selecting one of the two blue balls from each of the remaining three boxes.

So,

$$g(5) = \binom{4}{1} \times 2^3 = 32.$$

When $a = 6,$ you are selecting $4$ blue balls.  This means that you are selecting exactly one of the $2$ balls from each of the boxes.

So,

$$g(6) = 2^4 = 16.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$(81 \times 24) + (324 \times 32) + (594 \times 16) = 21816.$$