# Help me find the flaw in my method for this question based on combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider $4$ boxes, where each box contains $3$ red balls and $2$ blue balls.  In how many different ways can $10$ balls be selected from these four boxes so that from each box at least one red ball and at least one blue ball are chosen?

(A) $21816$

(B) $85536$

(C) $12096$

(D) $156816$

First, I go to one of the four boxes and select a red ball and a blue ball which I would be able to do in $3\times2$ ways or $6$ ways. Then I continue the process for all four boxes resulting in $6^4$ ways of selecting at least one red ball and one blue ball from all the four boxes. Now $8$ of the ten balls required haven been selected and each box now contains $2$ red balls and $1$ blue ball, making a total of $12$ unselected balls. Since all the $12$ balls are distinct, the number of ways of selecting the remaining $2$ required balls should be $12\choose2$. Therefore the final answer must be ${6^4}\times{12\choose2}$ which is $85536$. But the correct answer is apparently the $21816$. Where exactly did I go wrong?

Comment: In combinatorics, sometimes you can find the flaw in your method by trying it on a similar problem with smaller numbers. Supose I have just one box, containing just $2$ red balls. How many ways can I select $2$ balls (order doesn't motter) if **at least one of them must be red?** Let's see, first I have to select a red ball ($2$ ways), then one more ball ($1$ way), so my answer is $2\times1=2$. Why is that wrong?

Comment: More solutions to this problem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652568/choosing-10-balls-from-4-boxes-each-having-3-distinct-red-balls-and-2-di) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520907/find-number-of-ways-to-select-10-balls-such-that-at-least-one-red-ball-and-one).

Comment: @bof That really played with my intuition for a while. I will keep your advice in mind the next time I face a combinatorics proble.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the sources for more solutions

Comment: @bof i think the flaw actually is in the question. I think it should have been stated that balls with same color are distinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note your method gives repeated countings. We take the first bag for example, and we mark the three red balls as $r1, r2, r3$, two blue balls as $b1, b2$. If assume your last two balls are drawn from the first bag, you may have:

$$r1, b1, r2, r3$$

$$r2, b1, r1, r3$$

These are repeated countings, hence your answer is greater than the correct answer.

To avoid repeated countings, you may discuss it in two different cases:

Case.(1) Ten balls are distributed as $4, 2,2,2 $ ($4$ can be from the first, second, third , fourth bag)

$$4\cdot \left[\binom{5}{4}\cdot 6^3\right]=4320$$

Case.(2) Ten balls are distributed as $3,3,2,2$

$$\binom{4}{2}\cdot \left[\binom{5}{3}-1\right]^2\cdot 6^2=17496$$

Totally,

$$4320+17496=21816$$

Comment: Thank you for the response, it was difficult to see how there were repeated counting but finally the idea clicked in my head

Comment: Great, glad it helps.